# Unable to solve elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError in python for getting data from Elastic Search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, serialization, deserialization, mime-types

I am connected to remote ElasticSearch server and trying to get data from it but not able to solve SerializationError. it will be great if anyone can help me. any other approach using Python is appreciated

```
  from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
  import certifi
    es = Elasticsearch( ['23t4t273545273547288fr8t83rtf8.us-east-1.aws.found.io'],
         https_auth=('userid', 'pwd'),

         connection_class= (RequestsHttpConnection),
         port=9200,
         use_ssl=True,
         verify_certs=True,
         ca_certs=certifi.where(),
      )
        if es.ping():
            print('Yay Connect')
        else:
            print('Awww it could not connect!')


     search_param = {
        "query": {
            "terms": {
                "contentType": "criteria"
             }
            }
           }

response = es.search(index="content-page-rwr-v1", body=search_param)


print ('response:', response)
```

I am getting following error in python

```
Yay Connect
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Q:/MIS-DEV/QA/Pranit/PyCharm Projects/ALL Orig Scripts/ES.py", line 175, in <module>
response = es.search(index="content-page-rwr-v1", body=search_param)
File "C:\Python27\Env\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 76, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\Env\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\__init__.py", line 636, in search
doc_type, '_search'), params=params, body=body)
File "C:\Python27\Env\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 345, in perform_request
data = self.deserializer.loads(data, headers_response.get('content-type'))
File "C:\Python27\Env\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\serializer.py", line 79, in loads
raise SerializationError('Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: %s' % mimetype)
elasticsearch.exceptions.SerializationError: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: And when you query all .... body={'query':{'match_all':{}}}  resolve something??

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar same error if I use body={'query':{'match_all':{}}}

Comment: what version ES are you using??

Comment: @GiovaniSalazar I tried several versions for elasticsearch , as I heard about version might play role but still i am getting same issue. at present I am using elasticsearch 5.5.3
Do you any specific version that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is happening is that ES < 6.0 expects the content-type to be explicitly set in the header (specifically, application/json). You can modify the connection class to do this as suggested in [this github issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/407)